# Move semantic and an object-type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/4671213) answer about move semantic and come up with a problem. He describes the so-called move and swap idiom:

```
unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr source)   // note the missing reference
{
    std::swap(ptr, source.ptr);
    return *this;
}
```

Since the move assignment operator are supposed to operate on *rvalue* references, I thought that it's acceptable to pass the rvalue reference as an argument. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(){ }
    virtual ~A(){ }
    A(A&&){ }
};

void foo(A a){
    std::cout << "foo(A)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(*new A);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8440dc34f51e960b)

But the compiler warns me that it tried to copy the referenced object and failed because the copy-constructor is deleted. I don't udnerstand why it's correct in the example with `unique_ptr`. The object is supposed to be ***copied*** when we invoke the function, so there's no point of ***move*** semantic.

Couldn't you explain it a bit?

Comment: I'm not sure how strong your grasp of c++ is, the `*new T` is usually a giveaway of not understanding value semantics. What you would want in real life is `foo(A{});` but it's of course possible you know that and it's just academic.

Comment: `*new A` is an lvalue. It designates a memory location where an object is stored. To move you'd have to write `std::move(*new A)`  (which would leak memory)

Comment: "`*new A`", how are you going to `delete` that `A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move constructor is invoked to construct a new object from an *rvalue* of the same type. If you try to pass an *lvalue* to a function that takes a move-only type by value, it needs the *copy* constructor and you'll get an error.

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<Foo> p);
std::unique_ptr<Foo> p;
f(p);  // error
f(std::move(p));  // OK
```

In your example, it is possible to do this:

```
foo(std::move(*new A));
```

but `*new A` alone is not a possible argument, since dereferencing a pointer always produces an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `*(new A)` is not an rvalue.

The general rule (not [the actual rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues), just a quickie) for what expressions are rvalues is this: it's either a temporary or something you explicitly called `std::move` on. And `*(new A)` is not a temporary. And you didn't call `move` on it. So it's not an rvalue.

Try it with `A()` instead.